# Number of folders is returned as zero value

Tags: linux, shell

i am trying to count a number of folders which is passed as argument, and somehow a increment is returned as 0.
code looks like : 
`

```
all=ls $1 | grep $2
echo $all

k=0
for i in $all
do
  if [ -d "$i" ];then
k=$((k+1))
  fi
  echo $i
done
echo $k
```

fi

$1 is folder name and $2 is part of name of the folder.
So for example it should count number of folders inside folder.
Test folder has 3 more folders inside, and count should be 3, but i keep getting 0 Value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You script has many syntax issues.

To count folder inside a folder you can use this function:

```
cntdir() { local a=( "$1"/"$2"*/ ); echo "${#a[@]}"; }
```

Then call it as:

```
cntdir folder1 abc
```

- This function creates an array `a` using glob pattern `"$1"/"$2"*/` where `/` in the end makes sure that we're only matching directories.
- `${#a[@]}` gets count of array elements